# Prettier Reformatting

Tags: javascript, prettier

I've been trying to figure out how to change Prettier's format but can't seem to figure it out.

Prettier is reformating my code like this:

```
fetch(endpoint).then(blob =>
                blob.json().then(data => cities.push(...data))
            );
```

I want my code to reformat like this:

```
fetch(endpoint)
  .then(blob =>blob.json()
  .then(data => cities.push(...data))
);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it correct that you call `.then()` on the result of the `.blob()` call? Or is there a `)` missing in between the two? (I am not sure myself) Maybe the formatting will change if you fix this (if indeed it needs fixing).

Comment: If this is the actual code then the formatting doesn't make any sense from a semantic standpoint since the two `then` are explicitly not at the same "level".